# Errors after installation Breeze framework on ASP.NET Web Api Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, breeze

I have ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 project. I installed breeze via nuget on this project:

[image: breeze-via-nuget]

After installation Breeze framework I got errors and now I'm not able to build the project:

1. Error    Assembly 'System.Web.Http.OData, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  c:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.OData.dll
2. Error - Assembly 'System.Web.Http.OData, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.OData.dll

Although libraries are new version.

When I open "References" of my project in "Solution explorer" and double click on "System.Web.Http"

[image: references]

It opens "Object Browser" tab. And there I have a few versions of "System.Web.Http". H

[image: few versions]

ow can I say to use version I need?
How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of this issue is very simple. You need to delete a reference to the library from the project. Then check it was deleted in a bin folder. If not, delete it manually. Then add new reference to the required version of the library.

For some reasons VS doesn't replace a library when you reference to another version of the same library.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update the following settings in your web.config to something like this.
Seems like when you installed the nuget packages, the default web.config settings were not updated correctly.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: The same problen - It didn't help

Comment: Try deleting the reference and manually adding it back. It might take out those multiple versions.

Comment: I tried that, but when I add new version of dll it adds the old one

Comment: One last attempt...try my new answer. It is saying any version all the way to 5.2.2.0 should now use the new version of 5.2.2.0. I don't see the versions you have for System.Net.Http.Formatting. So, use the right version numbers based on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

@KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni - you gave him assembly redirects for everything EXCEPT the assembly identified in the message: `System.Web.Http.OData`!

Add this to the mix:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I've got a ton of these redirects in my apps. Here's the entire section from DocCode's *Web.config*:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.2.0" newVersion="5.6.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```